# what are angular with p-picklist specified actions?

Tags: angular, picklist

I have this angular code that shows 2 lists and moves items between them. I need to call a method when an item has been moved from the available list to the selected list
I tried using `(click)="refresh();"` but it runs the method on any click and I need to run it specifically when moving item from left to right

```html
<p-pickList (click)="refresh();" [source]="available" [target]="selected" sourceHeader="Available" targetHeader="Selected" [responsive]="true" filterBy="type" 
        dragdrop="true" dragdropScope="items" sourceFilterPlaceholder="Search by name" targetFilterPlaceholder="Search by name" [sourceStyle]="{'height':'300px'}" [targetStyle]="{'height':'300px'}">

    <ng-template let-items pTemplate="item">
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <div style="font-size:14px;margin:15px 5px 0 0">{{item.type}}</div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-pickList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `onMoveToTarget` method, and `onMoveToSource` method for vice versa, instead of calling `(click)` event.

Read more from the documentation

- https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/picklist

Comment: Glad to know :)

Comment: I accepted but trying to upvote it gives me:
Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.